# Minimum element from the matrix column

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, minimum

I need to find minimum over all elements from the column which has the maximum column sum.
I do the following things:

Create random matrix

```
from numpy import *
a = random.rand(5,4)
```

Then calculate sum of each column and find index of the maximum element

```
c = a.sum(axis=0)
d = argmax(c)
```

Then I try to find the minimum number in this column, but I am quite bad with syntax, I know how to find the minimum element in the row with current index.

```
e = min(a[d])
```

But how can I change it for columns?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can extract the minimum value of a column as follows (using the variables you have indicated):

```
e=a[:,d].min()
```

Note that using

```
a=min(a[:,d])
```

will break you out of Numpy, slowing things down (thanks for pointing this out @SaulloCastro).

Comment: you should use `a[:, d].min()` to guarantee that the NumPy method will be called, otherwise you will iterate over the array like in a Python iterable object (not at the C level)